Using Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) to send emails to dynamic audience
There is a system within a CMS that allows users to subscribe to content tagged with all manner of terms, and the subscription methods available are direct subscriptions to specific products (one of the aforementioned tags) or for them to tailor their own alerts with varying combination of tags. Then when a new piece of content is published, we find all the users who qualify as being subscribed to it (based on the tags applied to the content) and send out an email containing the published content. There is also the option to not have the email received immediately by the user but instead receive a digest on a daily, weekly or monthly basis.
We need to port this over to SFMC, and the emails getting sent out need to be trackable and have their opens logged, their clicks logged etc. Also, the sending of the realtime emails is very time critical. As soon as the content is published we need to send the email out straight away, within a few minutes, to potentially tens of thousands of users.
The CMS connects to Salesforce and also to SFMC via the respective API, and using these APIs will be what we use to complete this integration.
My idea was to use Data Extensions for this. All the possible recipients live in Salesforce as Contacts, and there is a synchronised Data Extension that contains all the Salesforce Contacts. But, the audience of these emails (as-and-when they get sent out) will be different, and potentially in the case of the digests the contents of the email will be different for each user. One email batch being sent might be to 100 users, but the next might be to 10,000. It all depends what the content is tagged with and what users are subscribed to what tags.
So seeing as the audience is essentially dynamic, my thinking was (via the SOAP API) to generate a new sendable Data Extension, populate it via a Query Definition using an SQL query that grabs data from the synchronised Data Extension and filters out just the Contacts I care about using an IN statement of Contact IDs, create an Email Content item, and send that email to the Data Extension using an Email Send Definition.
And, in the case of the digests, I'd use AMPScript in the Email Content to load the content applicable to that user from the CMS via a tokenised GET request (using HTTPGet).
Does this solution have any issues with it?
